# Error 520 Web server is returning an unknown error AWS (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, amazon-ec2

I have **AWS EC2** Instance and installed **Laravel** in that but i getting this error when multiple time hits URL.

We have also solution for that when we remove cookie problem is resolved but are not go with this solution.
Is there any solution for that

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the server logs?

Comment: Thanks your answer 
Not yet but when i remove browser cookie it's working fine. but remove cookie is not solution for that is there any another way ?